# Modulus/Modulo equivalent operator/function in django templates?

Tags: django, operators, templating

I'm just learning django's templating system and trying to do something relatively trivial:

```
<h2>State</h2>
<ul class="states">
{% for state in states %}
   <li class="state_elements" ><a href="/{{ state.name }}/"> {{ state.name }}</a></li>
   {% if forloop.counter \% 3 == 0 %}
   <br style="clear: both"/>
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

I get a syntax error because % is a symbol reserved for the templating language.  This is unfortunate.

I already found a partial solution with

```
{% cycle "" "" "" '<br style="clear: both"/>' %}
```

but it strikes me as damn odd.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**divisibleby**

*Returns True if the value is divisible by the argument.*

For example:

```
{{ value|divisibleby:"3" }}
```

[django template doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#divisibleby)

Comment: So just sanity check, could I do it as something like {% for.counter|divisibleby:"3" %} <br /> {% endif %}

Comment: {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:"3" %}

Answer (score 2):

**forlopp count divisible by 2**

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 == 0 %}
```

**forloop count not divisible by 2**

```
{% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:2 != 0 %}
```